# How to change image source context present inside rich text editor

Tags: blogs, image, cdn, rich-text-editor

I am developing a blog application. 
Initially I want everything to be hosted on a single Tomcat server and images to be served through tomcat only.

Problem that i am facing is while saving the content of rich text editor image sources are saved in database along with the application-context e.g.,

```
<img src="/application-context/image/abc.jpg">;
```

So if in future I want to go for any cdn or image servers separately, how should I design the application so that I am able to change image tags through property configuration only.
Below is what I am desiring

`<img src="http://www.myimageserver.com/image/abc.jpg">`;

Thanks